# Magento 2 Override Grid item Per Page

Tags: magento2, grid, custom

How to remove "200" and "Custom" in Item Per Page dropdwon?
[image]

Comment: I answered to you, but community don't like my answer so i deleted it. I encourage users that give minus to comment or give own answer, like the SO rules says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create `requirejs-config.js` here in your custom module

> app/code/SK/BackendUiHideCustomPerPage/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js

Content for this file is..

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/grid/paging/sizes': {
                'SK_BackendUiHideCustomPerPage/js/grid/paging/sizes-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now you need to create `sizes-mixin.js` file here in your custom module

> app/code/SK/BackendUiHideCustomPerPage/view/adminhtml/web/js/grid/paging/sizes-mixin.js

Content for this file is

```
define([
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'mageUtils',
    'uiElement'
], function (ko, _, utils, Element) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        defaults: {
            template: 'SK_BackendUiHideCustomPerPage/grid/paging/sizes',
            excludedOptions: ['200'],
        },

        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.excludedOptions.forEach(function (exclusion) {
                delete this.options[exclusion];
            }, this);

            this.updateArray();

            return this;
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

Now we will create template file here

> app/code/SK/BackendUiHideCustomPerPage/view/adminhtml/web/template/grid/paging/sizes.html

Content for this file is

```
<div class="selectmenu" collapsible="">
    <div class="selectmenu-value" openCollapsible="">
        <input type="text" ko-value="_value" attr="id: index" autoselect/>
    </div>
    <button class="selectmenu-toggle" type="button" css="_active: $collapsible.opened" toggleCollapsible>
        <span translate="'Select'"/>
    </button>
    <div class="selectmenu-items" css="_active: $collapsible.opened" outerClick="discardAll.bind($data)">
        <ul>
            <li repeat="foreach: optionsArray, item: '$size'" css="_edit: isEditing($size().value)">
                <div class="selectmenu-item-edit" if="$size().editable" keyboard="13: updateSize.bind($data, $size().value, false)">
                    <input class="admin__control-text" type="text"
                        ko-value="$size()._value" hasFocus="isEditing($size().value)"/>
                    <button class="action-save" type="button" click="updateSize.bind($data, $size().value, false)">
                        <span translate="'Save'"/>
                    </button>
                    <button class="action-delete" type="button" click="removeSize.bind($data, $size().value, false)">
                        <span translate="'Delete'"/>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="selectmenu-item">
                    <button class="selectmenu-item-action" type="button" text="$size().label" click="setSize.bind($data, $size().value)"/>
                    <button class="action-edit" type="button" if="$size().editable"
                        data-bind="
                            click: function () {
                                discardCustom().edit($size().value);
                            }">
                        <span translate="'Edit'"/>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<label class="admin__control-support-text" translate="'per page'" attr="for: index"/>
```

You can download this module [here](https://github.com/kishan-cybercom/magento2-override-grid-item-per-page-backend)

Now you need to run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**Output :**

[image]

This will work for all grids in backend.

Hope this will work for you!